# installing X11 on Fedora 16

Tags: x11, fedora

I wish to install X11 development libraries. I have Fedora 16 as OS. I found this link that offers source tar fies to X11R7.6.
http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/src/

Could you tell the next few steps?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to download the headers yourself, you can install them with yum, Fedora's package manager.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "X Software Development"
```

Comment: Note that, in general with Fedora (and Red Hat, CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, and so forth), it's almost always preferable (for a plethora of tiny reasons) to use the software manager (yum, apt-get, smart, ...) to grab components, whenever those components are available through that manager.